# How is it possible to revert to a prior version of macOS?

Tags: macos

I have a 2014 Macbook Pro, which always ran smoothly, without ever suffering the slightest delay when multi-tasking—even when encoding video with Handbrake, while playing a video in VLC, AND simultaneously working in an IDE like Visual Studio Code, it did it all without any noticeable delay.

Then, I upgraded to macOS Mojave (10.14.3). I noticed significantly decreased performance the first time I booted it. Now, even when opening a single app, with no other user apps running (i.e. no taskbar items or windowed apps; only system apps), there is an incredibly frustrating delay. VLC, in particular, is affected. It’s so slow to start, I have virtually enough time to go to the kitchen, grab a drink, and return to find VLC is *almost* ready to start running.

I have searched for running processes which consistently use large portions of RAM (it has 16GB RAM in total), but nothing stands out. Again, the contrast in performance between pre-installation of Mojave and post-installation was so stark, it was as if Apple had installed some sort of performance inhibitor (I’m being facetious, but the degradation is really egregious).

Assuming that reverting to the prior version is the best solution, what is the process for downgrading?

Note: the only other potential performance-degrading culprit I could find was the fact that my Macbook Pro is low on disk space. I have a lot of large work files (which I am in the process of moving to external storage). I suppose the free disk space varies between 6–30 GB.

Could having such a small amount of free space be the cause of its performance degradation, rather than the OS upgrade?

Comment: Have you done any research on this process or attempted anything yet? If you haven't, please do some research on your own and if you are stuck or having trouble let us know.

Comment: Basically, you can downgrade macOS but it’s not always a pretty or simple situation.

Comment: @music2myear I did research the issue—forgot to mention that. The problem wasn’t a lack of information, that’s for sure. I combed google results for days, but found no solutions.

Comment: @JakeGould Thanks. That’s actually the only thing I learned from my google research—the lack of an official downgrade method from Apple. It’s understandable (Android, anyone?), but still frustrating in this sort of situation. I was hoping you experts here might know something more than the bloggers I read did.  :)

Answer (score 3):

"free disk space varies between 6–30 GB" That's cause for concern.
You really should keep at least 10 - 15% free space, more if it's a small drive.

After a major update, the Mac will spend a couple of days re-indexing everything, which will cause additional speed hit & with Mojave will also be constantly running Time Machine local backups, which will eat that small remaining space, leaving the entire machine struggling to keep up.

Apple does not provide any support or simple method to revert to an older OS.
Reverting is only possible on a complete 'nuke & pave'. Wipe the machine & start over, re-install any apps & copy documents back from a backup. Things like Messages & mailboxes cannot be back-converted so you need copies from before the upgrade.

Ideally when prepping for a major OS upgrade you should ensure your Time Machine is fully up to date, then replace it before upgrading. That gives you a point to go back to, even though it will leave a gap between itself & any later work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I upgraded ~6 months ago, so indexing could be the culprit, but only if it’s still ongoing as you describe. I don’t use Time Machine; instead, I backup important directories manually to an external drive. Everything else could go, and I’d be fine. The thing is, again, the performance drop appeared only after upgrading to Mojave, which leads me to think the culprit might be connected to one of the new features in this version. I will take your advice & clear up disk space (I had about the same amount of free space in the prior OS version, though).

Comment: Time Machine runs local backups whether or not you actually use it. there's no way to switch it off. They're theoretically self-purging, but they will contribute to unreported disk space usage. Look at the volume in Disk Utility; the two figures for "Free" & "Available" show the difference.

Comment: Damn, I did not know that. Is it possible and safe to find & delete the TM backups, if they’re not being purged? I get why Apple did that, but local backups are useless to me. I wish there was a way to turn it off.

Comment: Have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340905/how-to-delete-all-local-timemachine-snapshots